# jQuery slideshow loop with asynchronously loaded images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple jQuery slideshow that doesn't load all of the images at start, the next image to be used will instead be loaded asynchronously to reduce the page size.

I have the slideshow working but the preload of the next image doesn't seem to be fully functioning?

**Exaple jQuery**

```
var i = 2;
var total = 9;

var obj = setInterval(function(){    

    $(".slides_container img").fadeOut("slow", function(){
        $(this).attr("src" ,"/images/slide-" + i + ".jpg").load(function() {
            $(this).fadeIn();
        });
    });

    if(i < total){
        i++;
        //Preload Next Image
        (new Image()).src = "/images/slide-" + i + ".jpg";
    }
    else   
        i = 1;
}, 4000);
```

**Possible Cause of the Issue**

The line underneath the preload comment must load the next image however the code highlighted below seems to not use any cached images but instead pull them from the server again?

I've had to use the `.load()` to make the `.fadeIn()` work correctly

```
$(this).attr("src" ,"/images/slide-" + i + ".jpg").load(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: You need to hook up the load event before you specify the SRC.

Comment: @Diodeus How should it be ordered within the load? `        $(".slides_container img").fadeOut("slow", function(){
            $(this).load(function() {
                $(".slides_container img").attr("src" ,"/images/slide/run-slide-" + i + ".jpg");
    $(".slides_container img").fadeIn();
            });
        });
`

Comment: $(this).load(...); in one line, then set the SRC is the second. You can run into situations where the image is cached and loads before the event handler is registered otherwise.

Comment: but if I do that then `.fadeIn()` doesn't work?

Comment: It should work. Can you post an example?

Comment: @Diodeus Could you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: Added response below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).attr("src" ,"/images/slide-" + i + ".jpg").load(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```

Should be:

```
$(this).load(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn();
});

$(this).attr("src" ,"/images/slide-" + i + ".jpg")
```

Or try: :

```
$(this).onload = function () {
   ....
})
```

Comment: I usually do this via straight JS. Try "onload" instead of "load".

Comment: it's working great now, I think: http://iwouldrun500miles.com, thanks for the help!